# What's the best way to show a CLI CRUD app to client?

Tags: client-relations

I'm developing a CRUD application on command line for a non-tech client. What's a simple (for both parties) way for me to demo the application remotely? A middle-ground between SSH (easy for me) and setting it up as a webapp (easy for the client) would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple ways you may consider:

1. Recording the presentation on your machine and sending a flv file to customer
2. Use web conferencing
3. Document presentation (power point, word, etc.) - Not very cool

Comment: I think Web Conferencing is the approach I would go for...